# simple PHP function call is no longer working

Tags: php

```
class blah{

    function a( x ){
    $variablename = b();
    ....
    }

    function b(){
    echo("why is this code (first line of function b) seemingly unreachable");
    ....
    }
}
```

it works fine when executed on a local server but not otherwise!?

Comment: Do you receive an error?

Comment: `variable` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: How are you calling it? Looks like you should have an undefined constant error for use of `variable = b();`.

Comment: it is in class so `$this->b()` isn't it ?

Comment: So much about that code is wrong that I suggest you study the basics before you ask questions here.

Comment: i should've called it '$variablename' i used it as an example

Comment: Check your logs, it must be full of PHP errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
$variable = $this->b();
```

if you call it from a non-static context. otherwise

```
$variable = self::b();
```

Comment: Why didn't I need to include `$this->` when I executed it on a local server?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing dollar signs ($) on all variables.

I'm actually amazed it worked on local.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
class blah{
    function a( $x ){
        $this->b(); // <---- added this ...
    }

    public function b(){
        echo("why is this code (first line of function b) seemingly unreachable");
    }

}

$test = new blah;
$test->a("some_string");
```